# How to extract text between two different xml tags multiline

Tags: java, regex, xml

For example we have some xml like this

```
<parent>
    <child>SomeText</child>sometext<otherChild>sometext</otherChild>
    <child>SomeText2</child>somtext2<otherChild>sometext2</otherChild>
</parent>
```

Which regex could be applied in order to extract content after `</child>` and before next `<child>` 
This string should be extracted `sometext<otherChild>sometext</otherChild>` in group 1, group 2 should include `somtext2<otherChild>sometext2</otherChild>`.

Already tried to apply regex like this but it works only for the first match

```
String textToParse = ...;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=</child>)(.*?)(?=<child>)", Pattern.DOTALL);

        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textToParse);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            LOGGER.info(matcher.group());
        }
```

Comment: what about [idene demo](https://www.ideone.com/NcJiwh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=</child>)(.*?)(?=<child>|</parent>)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Add the `|</parent>` because in the last match there is no next `<child>` tag.

Also you should do `matcher.find()` and `matcher.group()` again to get to the next match.